# Adding a timeslider controller to openlayers

Tags: jquery, slider, openlayers-3, geoserver

I have a database that contains some weather data in a `.csv` format. Each table represents the weather condition at specific point in time.
Using the geoserver, I can visualise each of these tables on my browser. 
What I have been searching for a way to do, is something to add as slider to my `html` code, so it shows the weather condition at each minute, as I slide across the slider.

I have found some `.js` code here, but honestly speaking, don't know where to add to fit my purpose (or even if it really fits the purpose or not)

https://github.com/metno/openlayers-timeslider

Also, I don't know if this would be helpful, but the part of the `html` that shows the data on the map is as following:

```
var rainLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
  url: 'http://x.x.x.x/geoserver/wms',
  params: {'LAYERS': 'storename:layername'}
});
```

Comment: You don't really provide enough detail here to help you specifically.  You mention 'Each table represents ... at a specific point in time'.  You'll want to arrange this data in a single table through some ETL process.  You'll then need to configure your layer to have time series awareness.  This link [http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/webadmin/layers.html#data-webadmin-layers-edit-dimensions] describes how to do it in version 2.11. You may also want to consider using Leaflet if your requirement for openlayers isn't firm.  [http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#time--elevation]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ImageMosaic](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/index.html#data-imagemosaic) plugin for raster time-series data of Geoserver.
[Here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html) is the documentation for implementing a time enabled ImageMosaic.
after implementing the mosaic you need to pass the time parameter to the geoserver in the openlayers like this:

```
var wms = new ol.layer.Tile({
            name: name,
            opacity: opacity,
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: global.geoserverWMS2 + 'wms',
                params: {
                    'LAYERS': layer_name,
                    'TILED': true,
                    'TIME': '2017-01-01', // this is an example
                },
                serverType: 'geoserver'
            })
        });
```

and once you wanted to change the time parameter in order to render the corresponding weather image just use the updatePrams() on the wms layer like this:

```
wms.getSource().updateParams({'time': '2016-01-01'})
wms.getSource().updateParams({'time': '2015-01-01'})
wms.getSource().updateParams({'time': '2014-01-01'})
```

and it will refresh the data source and render the new imagery.